# SSL Pinning - Bypassing Pinning that uses .pem

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, pinning

Im attempting to test Spotify and it uses a "cacert.pem" file signed by Equifax Secure Certificate Authority.

Is it possible to bypass that and get the requests? At the moment im unable to sniff it. (Attempting to use Fiddler)

Comment: If Spotify has configure all traffic to use the certificate then you won’t be able to bypass the certificate.  That’s the entire point.

Comment: @Ramhound there has to be a way around it no? All I need is to get the url, headers and post data.

Comment: If you want all that data, over an insecure connection, then you cannot get around it.  Spotify can also configure their server in such a way, it will reject any connection from a client, that is attempting to perform a MiTM attack which is basically what you have to do in order to intercept secure HTTP traffic in order to display it in something like Fiddler.

Answer (score -1):

Download the file cacert.pem
 
Open cacert.pem in notepad++
Copy public key hash
Go to the report-uri website
Click on the tab named tools
Scroll down to HPKP Generator (PEM)
Paste the public key hash
Click the hash button
With this 1 public key hash,
 
i think you should be able too bypass when,
you give the software your using to sniff.
 
The sniffing software could use this 1 public key hash,
to complete the pinning steps to
 
begin the sniff test of your website.

Comment: Wheres the public key hash?

Comment: Also I dont think Fiddler or anything can use a hash